# Outer measure is not finitely additive

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I know similar questions have been asked before, but I'm looking for clarification of a proof. In Royden's book on real analysis, he proves that every set of positive measure contains a non-measurable set.

To prove that outer measures are not finitely additive, he proves the following claim: there are disjoint sets $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$ for which $m^{*}(A \cup B) < m^{*}(A) + m^{*}(B)$.

His proof goes as follows: Assume $m^{*}(A \cup B)= m^{*}(A) + m^{*}(B)$ for every disjoint pair of sets $A$ and $B$. Then, by the definition of measurable set, every set must be measurable. This contradicts the preceding theorem (that every set of positive measure contains a non-measurable set).

I'm not exactly seeing the contradiction. Are the details of the proof that every set of positive measure contains a non-measurable set relevant?

Comment: What definition for measurable are you using? I believe you will need the previous result. Say $A$ is a set of positive measure, it has a subset $C$ that is not measurable, and notice that $A = A \setminus C \cup C$ is a disjoint union. You want to show that $C$ is measurable, then you get your contradiction.

Comment: Royden uses the definition that $f$ is measurable if $\{x \in X: f(x) > \alpha\}$ is measurable for any $\alpha \in \overline{\mathbb{R}}$. The previous theorem he proves involves constructing a non-measurable Vitali set.

Comment: That's what he uses to define what it means for a function $f$ to be measurable, how does he define what it means to be a measurable **set** in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: I believe that he defines a measurable set to be a set in the $\sigma$-algebra obtained by completing the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. I believe that's called the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra, or something similar?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I haven't seen Royden but one of the equivalent definitions of Lebesgue measurability is the following: $E$ is Lebesgue measurable if for every $X$,

$$m^{\star}(X) = m^{\star}(E \cap X)+ m^{\star}(E^c \cap X)$$

So, if you assume that $m^{\star}(A \cup B) = m^{\star}(A) + m^{\star}(B)$ whenever $A, B$ are disjoint, then it follows that every set is measurable - Since $X$ is a disjoint union of $E \cap X$ and $E^c \cap X$.

Luzin improved this to the following: For every $X$, there are disjoint $A, B \subseteq X$ such that $m^{\star}(X) = m^{\star}(A) = m^{\star}(B)$.

Comment: I now realize my confusion. Proof by contradiction requires negating the claim, which just amounts to having $m^{*}(A \cup B) \geq m^{*}(A) + m^{*}(B)$ for all disjoint sets $A,B$. Since we have the reverse inequality by countable subadditivity of outer measure, this implies that every set is measurable. And that obviously contradicts the theorem I brought up. Thanks for bringing things into perspective.

Comment: This is too late, but do you have a link / reference to the Luzin's theorem you refer to above ?