# $E_1$ and $E_2$ are disjoint then $m(E_1\cup E_2)=m(E_1)+m(E_2)$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

My professor told me that the following statement is not always right:

> $E_1$ and $E_2$ are disjoint then $m_*(E_1\cup E_2)=m_*(E_1)+m_*(E_2)$

where $m_*(\cdot)$ denotes the outer measure. However I'm not sure why, because I learned a theorem of the following:

> If $E=E_1 \cup E_2$, and $d(E_1, E_2)>0$, then $m_*(E)=m_*(E_1)+m_*(E_2)$

So I think my problem with this part is that I can't distinguish the difference between 'being disjoint', and 'having a positive measure'. What will be some example of sets that are disjoint, yet has zero distance, or not disjoint, yet has a positive distance.

Edit: Thanks to the answer of @Giorgio Zorzi detto Giorgione, I have an example of sets that are disjoint, yet has zero distance, namely the rational and irrationals. I think I got the difference between them. However, if we take $E_1=[0, 1]\cap Q$ and $E_2=[0, 1]\cup Q^C$, we still notice that the first statement holds. Then, in which particular cases does the first statement not hold, and if this difference is not coming from "disjoint" and "positive distance", where is it coming from?

Comment: Your confusion comes from the fact that additivity of the outer lesbegue measure holds for lesbegue measurable sets such as the rationals and irrationals, even without the further assumption of positive distance.
Therefore a suitable counterexample has to involve non-measurable sets, see e.g. here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998402/outer-measure-is-not-finitely-additive .

Comment: @unwissen Thanks for your comment. I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Pick the rationals and the irrationals. Their distance is zero (by definition of distance, which involves an infimum) but they are disjoint.

If the distance between two sets is not zero, this implies they are disjoint.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you perhaps read the edit, and tell me where my confusion is coming from?

Comment: the final sentence is a typo???

Comment: Sure! thanks David